# Text-file class python

Tags: python, class, text-files

Here is the problem I am working on:

Develop a class Textfile that provides methods to analyze a text file. The class Textfile will support a constructor that takes as input a file name (as a string) and instantiates a Textfile object associated with the corresponding text file. The Textfile should support methods nchars(), nwords(), and nlines() that return the number of characters, words, and lines, respectively.

Here is my attempt at the problem:

```
class Textfile():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.file = open(filename)

    def nchars(self):
        return len(self.file.read())

    def nwords(self):
        content = self.file.read()
        words = content.split()
        return len(words)

   def nlines(self):
        content = self.file.read()
        return content.count('\n')
```

All of my methods seem to work. However, when I run two methods consecutively, the text-file is not saved for the second method and I get 0.

For instance,
Let example.txt = This is a sentence.

When I run the program, I should get this

```
>>>>x = Textfile('example.txt')
>>>>x.nchars()
>>>>19
>>>>x.nwords()
>>>>4 
>>>>x.nlines()
>>>>1
```

However, I get this

```
>>>>x = Textfile('example.txt')
>>>>x.nchars()
>>>>19
>>>>x.nwords()
>>>>0 
>>>>x.nlines()
>>>>0
```

or this:

```
>>>>x = Textfile('example.txt')
>>>>x.nwords()
>>>>4
>>>>x.nchars()
>>>>0 
>>>>x.nlines()
>>>>0
```

As you can see, the methods work individually but the text-file is not saved in the next method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After you `.read()` the file, the "read head" is at the end. `.seek(0)` to "rewind". Alternatively, count and store all values in `__init__` then you don't even need to keep the file open.

Comment: You need to rewind the file after you `read` in each method. Try using self.file.seek(0,0).

Comment: @jonrsharpe That looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the `read()` function only goes through a file once. As you read, it moves where it is in the file buffer. During your functions, you reach the end of the file. You'd need to close and reopen the file in order to do what you're doing. I recommend remaking your init function to be:

```
def __init__(self, filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as inputfile:
        self.content = inputfile.read()
```

And then use content everywhere instead of read. It will allow for reusability and safety if your program crashes due to surprisingly losing the file handle.

As @chepner aded, it's probably also better practice to edit your `__init__` to also include the length and count (and other) properties, so that the contents themselves don't have to be held in memory. This would look like

```
def __init__(self, filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as inputfile:
        content = inputfile.read() 
    self.nChars = len(content)
    self.nLines = content.count('\n')
    self.nWords = len(content.split())
```

Comment: Given that reading from disk is probably much, much slower than processing the resulting data, you may as well precompute the counts in `__init__` and simply return the appropriate result from each function, rather than keep the file contents in memory.